# Can I test my Flash animation, starting x frames in, and still have sound playback?

Tags: flash, adobe-flash

Forgive me because I'm a Flash newbie. I'm putting together a simple animation, and I have an MP3 file that starts playing in its own layer on Frame 1. When I hit Control > Play to test it out, this works fine as long as I start from the first frame -- but not any other frame.

While I'm testing it, I want to be able to start the animation from frame 1,000, or 2,000, and still have the sound playing (at the correct point in the audio file), rather than having to re-watch the whole thing up to that point every time.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out -- all I had to do was set the "Sync" type to "Stream" (instead of "Event") on the frame.